# Grails 3.0.1 not honoring application.yml mongo config

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-3.0

Trying to start Grails 3.0.1 app using only mongodb. The mongo plugin does not seem to be reading the mongo config in the application.yml file. I've putting it in the environments development section, outside the environments section, etc. but it just uses default config of localhost:27017 and db name of 'test'.

here is the current config:

```
// default application.yml stuff
environments:
  development:
   grails:
      mongo:
         host: 'ip_address_here'
         port: 27017
         databaseName: 'app_dev'
   test:
// rest of application.yml stuff
```

As a test, in the BootStrap I dumped out the grailsApplication.config data and the mongo stuff does appear there, so it is getting loaded.

Comment: Please file a bug report at https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb/src/main/groovy/grails/mongodb/bootstrap/MongoDbDataStoreSpringInitializer.groovy) for all configuration options.
Note especially "mongodb" instead of just "mongo"

Comment: changing to mongodb works for everything but the databaseName. Looking at the code, it appears the databaseName is only recognized if a connection string it used (and verified through testing). However the format I showed above working in a grails 2.4.x app using this plugin.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I am using a connection string, that is why it works at me. But you have definitely found a bug! Please file it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the configuration that works for me with

Grails 3.0.1
org.grails.plugins:mongodb:4.0.0

```
environments:
    development:
        grails:
            mongodb:
                connectionString: "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test"
                autoConnectRetry: true
                connectTimeout: 0
                maxWaitTime: 120000
                socketTimeout: 0
                socketKeepAlive: false
                writeNumer: 0
                writeTimeout: 0
                writeFsync: false
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a connection string, but also submitted a patch to get the other method to work a couple weeks ago. I don't think it has been accepted yet though.

Comment: The `connectionString` workaround did it.  The URI format is documented at: http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html

Answer (score 0):

Documentation might be little confusing, this should do the trick with auth

```
 connectionString: "mongodb://myUserName:myPassword@ipOfServer:portOfServer/dbName"
```